# What exactly would a distance labeled Bahnhöhe mean in the context of a satellite's orbit around the Earth?

Tags: german-to-english, technical-terminology

[This answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/39066/7982) refers to information in this German Wikipedia page [Technology Experiment Satellite](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Experiment_Satellite)

The page contains the following information:

I recognize apogee and perigee, inclination and period.

I don't see semi-major axis, but if it were there it would be the simple average of apo and peri, and in this case 541 km.

There I see Bahnhöhe  mentioned several times in Wikipedia's [Satellitenorbit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satellitenorbit), but what exactly does it mean?

```
Umlaufzeit:       95,3 min[1]
Bahnhöhe:         572 km
Bahnneigung:      97.7°
Apogäumshöhe:     567 km
Perigäumshöhe:    515 km

[1]  Bahndaten nach [TES](https://www.n2yo.com/satellite/?s=26957). N2YO, 18. November 2017, abgerufen am 18. November 2017
```

Comment: Höhe is altitude, Bahn is orbit. The question that you refer to already had that information. I do not think that possible inconsistencies in the data are language related.

Comment: @CarstenS there are comments under the question yes, but 1) I'm not certain of their validity and completeness, and 2) altitude doesn't make sense. Since words can sometimes have multiple meanings or usages in different contexts, I decided to open this up to this SE community; it's possible that there are more than one answer.

Comment: Have a look at https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erdn%C3%A4he: „In der Raumfahrt hingegen ist für erdnahe Satelliten die Bahnhöhe über der Erdoberfläche die entscheidende Größe: die Bahnhöhe im Perigäum, also die Perigäumshöhe, wird dabei häufig selbst als Perigäum bezeichnet.[1][2] Entsprechend wird die Bahnhöhe im Apogäum, also die Apogäumshöhe, kurz Apogäum genannt.“ The term itself really is not more specific.

Comment: Maybe you'll find your answer here: [Sun-synchronous orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun-synchronous_orbit) ?

Comment: Apogee 567 km, Bahnhöhe (= altitude of orbit) 572 km?

Comment: It literally means what "altitude" means in english in he same context. What you have found is a inconsistency in data, but its not a language-related problem, its a data problem. You obviously can't have an orbit with an altitude higher than apogee.

Comment: The 572km comes from the ISRO page. "Orbit 572 km Sun Synchronous" (https://www.isro.gov.in/Spacecraft/technology-experiment-satellite-tes). I think somebody just copied together the data without cross-checking for consistency and didn't notice the discrepancy.

Comment: @uhoh: Please edit your question on what you "recognize" - and how/why (e.g. the german words). And what you looked for to miss "semi-major axis". Because you used translations here and I'm not aware of these words in the right meaning. And meaning is with *Bahnhöhe* what is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of astronomy, the German word *"die Bahn"* means *"the orbit".* And *"die Höhe"* is *"the altitude".*

Together:

> Bahnhöhe = altitude of an orbit

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still wondering; does bahnhöhe apply to the entire orbit, or only to a specific point in the orbit? Any orbit that isn't circular can not have a single altitude. In English the only time I've seen an orbit's altitude mentioned is in the context of a circular orbit around a spherical body.

Comment: @uhoh: This question is out of the scope of German.stackexchange. I've studies physics, and I am very interested in astronomy, but I can't answer your question. For me this term simply makes no sense, especially not in the presence of two well defined terms like apogee and perigee.

Comment: Okay I see, thanks for the clarification. In that case, unless something else is posted soon I'll accept this as an answer.

Comment: Doesn't "Bahn" first and foremost act as a shortened version of "Flugbahn" (roughly: "flight path"), which *in this case* is an orbit?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: This is exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Also the data do not make sense. With an apogee of 567 km it is impossible that the altitude of orbit is 572 km.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Neither does your answer contain a hint what "Bahn" might be a shortened form of, nor whether it is exactly synonymous with "orbit". Note that I'd like to somewhat correct myself in both points, though: Come to think of it, instead of "Flugbahn", an equally likely alternative is "Umlaufbahn". Furthermore, after some reading up, I have realized that "Bahn" on its own is indeed used a lot in astronomical texts, seemingly as a set term rather than a lengthy compound shortened ad hoc. Second, I couldn't find any clear statements on whether "Flugbahn" and "Orbit" could be ...

Comment: ... synonyms, but if "Bahn" is based on "Umlaufbahn", that consideration is a moot point. Thus, maybe both points were based on the confusion by someone who has *not* studied physics ;)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: What is unclear with this sentence *»In the context of astronomy, the German word "die Bahn" means "the orbit".«* The Word *»Bahn«* is not based on *»Umlaufbahn«.* The opposite is true: The words *Flugbahn, Umlaufbahn, Kreisbahn, Ellipsenbahn, Erdumlaufbahn, Satellitenbahn* etc are compound words containing *»Bahn«* are their last Element, so »Bahn« is **NOT** based on Umlaufbahn or any of the other words. All these words are based on *»Bahn«*. Fact is, that the question was *»What does Bahnhöhe mean in the context of an satellite's orbit?«* And I answered this question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, on an elliptic orbit, there is:

- Perigäumshöhe (die Bahnhöhe im Perigäum, short: Perigäum) and
- Apogäumshöhe (die Bahnhöhe im Apogäum, short: Apogäum)

The mean value is: die Bahnhöhe.

Comment: This doesn't check out. PH: 515. AH: 567, mean: 541. But above Bahnhöhe is 572.

Comment: @infinitezero: nope, look at the English page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technology_Experiment_Satellite . Perigee altitude 551 km, Apogee altitude 579 km

Comment: With those values, the mean value is still not the 572 mentioned above. So stating that the Bahnhöhe is the mean value, seems dubious to me, without other prove.

Comment: For those who still didn't get it: There are wrong values on wikipedia! And values of orbital heights are **NOT** topic of German.stackexchange. Please discuss those values where this discussion belongs to: on Wikipedia.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I'm the OP and the topic of the question is the meaning of Bahnhöhe, not "values of orbital heights". The question of orbital heights is in a different SE site and linked in my question. I simply mentioned the situation there as potentially helpful background. If one doesn't find it helpful, then one does not need to pursue it. "A problem in Wikipedia was mentioned, therefore off-topic" is a bit extreme, no?

Comment: @uhoh: No, it's not extreme. If a problem on Wikipedia is about German language, then it is ok to discuss it here too. But what is discussed here is not about German language. The discussion here is about how orbital height is related to apogee and perigee. This is not a discussion about aspects of German language but about astronomy and therefore offtopic on a site that is made to discuss aspects of German language.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast I think I understand, this answer is "off topic" in nature, got it. I see the question is closed and I understand the reason, and since I have a sufficient understanding I don't think I need to try to reopen it. Thanks to all for the help!